# What strategy might I use to find a question to place a bounty on?

Tags: discussion

So. I've been looking at the *altruist* and *investor* badges, and was wanting to add them to my collection. However I don't want to just put a bounty on any old rubbish question. Equally I don't want to just add yet more rep on an already highly up voted answer.

So is there any strategy I can use to find a question or answer that is deserving of a bounty but doesn't currently have a high score?

It's easy to find popular or highly voted questions, but they don't need more reputation. What I'd like to find is a high quality question or high quality answer that is not achieving as much recognition as it deserves. How might I go about doing that?

Comment: *"What I'd like to find is a high quality question"* Isn't this what we're all looking for..? :p

Comment: Look in less than popular tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, I wouldn't bother.  You'll get those badges if and when you get them, but there's little actual point in deliberately chasing after them.

That said, if you *really* want them, you could just go through the [unanswered questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered), and look for a good question that doesn't have an answer yet.

([Here's one I recently found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043278/how-to-know-if-a-page-loaded-via-iframe-is-within-sandbox)  I might give it a bounty myself, because I'd really like to see if there are any good answers to it; but I already have those badges on SO, so if you'd like to do the honors instead, be my guest. :)

Comment: Couldn't bounty that one but bountied the dupe. That's the sort of question I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: Had an answer on the bountied question that looks good. Check if it does what you need and if it does I'll award the bounty.

Comment: @TimB: It may be an answer, but honestly, I don't think it's a very good one, since it just links to a library. Now, an answer describing *what the library does* (which, at a glance, doesn't really seem very complicated) would be a good one. I may have to take a closer look and see if I can make a better answer myself.

Comment: Yeah, I added a comment to that effect myself, essentially it's close to a link-only answer at the moment.